# Smithing low level legendary set items

Tags: diablo-iii

I recently got Reaper of Souls, yes I know I'm late. I've been levelling up my characters to level 70 and I've been looking around for gear and gearing tips, and I've found that some of the legendary set items that I've already found the plans for (Aughild's, Captain Crimsons etc) are pretty good to start off with for a Demon Hunter which is my most recent levelling character.

I found these plans at a low level, and I tried to craft one of the items on my level 70 Wizard and it came up with lower stats and a level requirement of 42, which is when I found them and taught them to Haedrig, I also tried to enchant and I won't be able to get anything useful, is this a problem, is there anything I can do to increase the potency of this gear? if it's the best gear to start off with at level 70 then I'd like to be able to start off with it, but if I can't craft it to a good enough standard, then I won't be able to use it.

Sorry if this may seem a little hard to understand, I'm a little flustered and confused, and I will try and re write it or re word it if the meaning isn't understood. Basically is there a way I can raise the level requirement and the stats on set items I may need to start my level 70 journey?

Comment: @Chessbrain For story, yes. But (as a D2, TQ, TQ:IM, BL, BL2, BLTPS, D3, D3:RoS player) I'd say D3's gameplay and progression are much more polished (now, in version 2.2). So, if you play the game for the gameplay itself, D3 probably will come as a winner. Still, this only applies after experiencing story, art style and environment, and these are still good in TQ.

Comment: @CraigHarris, generally what you find at low levels is only good for those low levels. So, pre-70 crafted sets can be very powerful for a new character, when you already have the plan learned and materials stacked up. Apart from that, not really useful, yes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22793/discussion-between-orc-jmr-and-chessbrain).

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem you are encountering is that there are two versions of most crafted sets. For example, there is [Aughild's Victory](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/aughilds-vestments) which requires level 42 and there is [Aughild's Authority](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/aughilds-rule) which requires level 70. Since you have the plans for Aughild's Victory, you will only be able to craft the level 42 version unfortunately.

When Reaper of Souls was released, Blizzard updated a lot of the legendary and set gear that previously existed for level 60 characters to be for level 70 characters. They did this by leaving the old items in the game (since there might be characters using it already) and making new items that require level 70.

What you most likely read about are the level 70 versions of these crafted sets. They are indeed very good for a level 70 character that is just starting out. These plans can drop off of any mob in the game, so there isn't a good spot to farm them (other than to just keep playing the game, of course). I don't know if this is documented anywhere or not, but I have found that the treasure goblin that drops crafting materials also tends to drop crafting plans - these have been legendary or set plans in my experience (until you have learned them all).

Comment: Odious collector's do tend to drop 3-4 plans per kill until you find a few. Though they can sometimes be duplicates.

Comment: Plans that drop are never one of those which you Artisans already know. If, however, the plan just sits in your inventory or several drop at once, there may be duplicates, so you better teach everyting you find to Artisans ASAP... Or, well, collect an entire stash tab of Blitzbolet plans like [this guy](http://i.imgur.com/YhQTblU.jpg) :-)

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot increase the level of low level sets. Start out by equipping yellow level 70 items with a lot crit and crit damage. That is all you need.

Those low level sets are meant for alts to have it easier leveling up when you can afford spending a lot of souls on it.

Comment: Yeah, I know, I thought that was what they are for, but I've seen other level 70's using those sets that I've mentioned in my post so I was wondering if there was anything that I was able to do

Comment: @CraigHarris You can find level 70 versions of the plans for those sets - that's what you'll need to find

Comment: @JonK Ok, thank you, and the Blacksmith will learn those new level plans? sorry, I really don't know much about the game, or at least the end game